# Do I need to config https in my app if https already configured in nginx

Tags: api, nginx, https, .net-core, backend

I've seen some articles about how to add `https` to `.Net Core` app.

And I don't understand I need to config https for my '.Net Core' API service or not, because I've already configured `Nginx` for it.

I think this question is relevant for any backend type not only for '.Net Core'

My `Nginx` config looks like there:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    error_page 404 = 301 http://page.example.com/;
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything for your app in regards to `HTTPS` as the `nginx` is terminating the SSL and changing to HTTP in this case. What you should do is pass the schema something like `proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` so if needed your app can know via the header when the schema is `HTTPS` and make choices based on that.

Comment: @ShawnC Your comment may be an answer, maybe you are able to add more arguments, but at least it's what I wanted to hear

Answer (score 1):

Your NGinx is now setup for https, but your app also needs to be redirected to https. You'll need to create an .htaccess file and you'll need to define to redirect to https instead of standard http.

Here's the complete manual for forcing https:
[Forcing Https by Inmotion hosting](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file)

Comment: My question is not about how to do it, it's not complicated. My question is about necessary adding `https` to my app if I've already configured `Nginx` for it . And my data already protected and connection is safe enough and reliable via `Nginx`

Comment: HTTPS adds security and trust. Moreover Google started to use HTTPS as a search ranking signal in 2014, meaning that websites available over HTTPS get an advantage in search results over those that don't encrypt their connections. Also it will trigger security alerts in users' browsers.